# Azure Logic Apps - Dropbox Connector Filesize Limit

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple Logic App which lists files in a Dropbox folder, then copies them to an Azure Blob container.  Works great!  However, when a file is larger than 50MB (like 100MB in this example), I get the following error:

```
{
  "status": 413,
  "message": "The file contains 100.514 megabytes which exceeds the maximum 50 megabytes.\r\nclientRequestId: <someid>",
  "source": "dropbox-cus.azconn-cus.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

That limit does not appear to exist on either Dropbox or Blob Storage.  Is there a way to make that connector limit larger?

Comment: Which particular actions are you using? I can't find the related limits too, but the `50 MB` (coincidentally?) matches the limits on other protocols: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#b2b-protocols-as2-x12-edifact-message-size

Comment: I'm using the "Get File Content" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team confirms that 50 MB is the default file size limit for the Dropbox connector and can't be changed at the your end. However, your question is great feedback as a feature, so please provide more details about your use case at the [Logic Apps - Connectors User Voice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/filters/hot?category_id=145803).

That way, others can vote, which helps the team prioritize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm relaying the information from another answer, which does not directly target same exact technologies, but is definitely related to Logic Apps.

> Logic App have maximum message size limits, and seems like you are hitting one of them.
>
> So, if you need to use logic apps, you would need to have smaller messages.
>
> [Source: MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fcaf1613-088a-4a27-8b24-e6dbb0a7c119/data-management-gateway-file-size-limitation)

---

*Maybe* you can contact support and ask them to increase your limits.